# read all files in sub folder with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-analysis, python-os

My notebook is in the home folder where I also have another folder "**test**". In the **test** folder, I have 5 sub folders. Each of the folder contains a .shp file. I want to iterate in all sub folders within test and open all .shp files. It doesn't matter if they get overwritten.

```
data = gpd.read_file("./test/folder1/file1.shp")
data.head()
```

How can I do so? I tried this

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path + "/test/", "*.shp"))
print(files)
```

but this would only go in 1 layer deep.

Comment: what about just passing `path + "/test/"` to `path.join`? e: Tested and works for me

Comment: Sorry, I updated my qs @Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the os.walk method in the os library.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./test"):
    for name in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(root, name)
        data = pd.read_file(fpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do os.chdir(path), and then use glob.glob(os.path.join('*.shp')). It should work.
You have already given the string to join 'os.path'.

Comment: Is this for the updated qs? How do I iterate within the folders inside test?

Comment: For your current qs, u could do what I said. It should work.