# Get the file path for files in nested folders using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to print the file path for the files and not directories located in nested folders using pandas. The path where the folder is located changes. The code should read the dynamic file path and print the path where the csv files are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the os library with the method walk.

You have few examples here:

[read all files in sub folder with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669247/read-all-files-in-sub-folder-with-pandas)

[Do I understand os.walk right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989005/do-i-understand-os-walk-right)

Comment: Please don't post links to duplicates as answers. Once you have enough reputation, you will be able to vote to close as duplicate, or leave a comment.